# Undefined index in PHP post with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my local machine, I am trying to save data from a json to my mysql database, I am using Wampserver.

In my html page (saveInfo.php), I have this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var jsObj = {"user_id":5, "login":"hsm"};
            var jsonobj = JSON.stringify(jsObj);            
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "json_handler.php",  
                data: { 'jsonobj':jsonobj },      
                success: function(){  
                  alert('success');
                  window.location = "http://localhost/quranMapping/php/json_handler.php";
                } 
            });
</script>
```

In the other side, I have my server-side php code (`json_handler.php`) like that:

```
<?php

$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = $_POST['jsonobj'];

$result = json_decode($input);

echo $result->user_id;

?>
```

But when I run that code, I get this error:
[image]

Comment: this could mean that $_POST['jsonobj'] is not getting set. You need to make sure that the value of jsonobj is getting passed to the php page.

Comment: what is in `var_dump($result)` ?

Comment: It looks like the variable isn't making it as far as PHP. Can you `var_dump($_POST)` and output what comes out. Also, use Firefox or Chrome to get a dump of your outgoing POST request and post it up here too.

Comment: try `console.log(jsonobj);` in your js.

Comment: Yeah it is not set, this is the problem, but how can garantee that jsonobj is getting passe plz?

Comment: @Venkat It's not a deprecated error. And turning it off won't magically pass the POST value. Please people stop suggesting error silencing as a solution

Comment: `data: { jsonobj:jsonobj }` without quotes.

Comment: The result of console.log is : {"user_id":5,"login":"hsm"}

Comment: withouts qoutes did not give the result

Comment: var_dump($result) give empty result

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` then

Answer (score 3):

You should remove this:

```
var jsonobj = JSON.stringify(jsObj);
```

and change

```
data: { 'jsonobj':jsonobj },
```

to

```
data: jsObj,
```

On the php side to decode the data just use

```
$user_id = isset($_POST["user_id"])?$_POST["user_id"]:"";
$login   = isset($_POST["login"])?$_POST["login"]:"";
```

Also there is no need to do

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Since the form is being posted with an object as data the value will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so it don't be valid json.

Comment: Named `jsonobj` on the client, but `jsObj` on the server?

Comment: array (size=0) : this was the output

Comment: @HoussemBdr that is the value of `var_dump($_POST["jsonobj"]);` ?

Comment: @HoussemBdr See updates ... there is no reason to wrap the two object in another object... this should give your the data you want right in the $_POST array

Comment: echo "user is : ".$user_id; gave empty result : (

Comment: the erro was "undefiened variable"

Comment: are you assigning $user_id from the $_POST array value?