# Undefined index on ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

[image]This might seem like a duplicate question, but it isn't. I have searched google but my bug remains.

The issue is that the php script can not set $_POST array to the value being passed by the ajax post request. I have a form that,when submitted,displays another form in the same divs as the first form. The second form contains a submit button, as well as a button which sends ajax post request but it's value is not being set by php. The code is as follows:

html code: it is to pick out value of the span.

```
<i>Current Balance: <span id="bal_val"><?php echo $b; ?></span></i>
<div id="bal" style='color:green;'>
```

Ajax code:
here, edit button is a button (of the first form) which enables the display of the second form. The second form contains the balbutton input,which sends ajax request.

```
 $('#edit').click(function(event){  
          event.preventDefault();
$('#bal').html('<button class="btn1 btn-1 btn-1b" id="balbutton" name="balbutton">Add 1000 Rs.</button>');
});

$('#balbutton').click(function(event){
              event.preventDefault();

              var bal = document.getElementById('bal_val').innerHTML;
              var balance = parseInt(bal);
             var dataString = {balance};

               $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "admin.php/",
                                    data: dataString,
                                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    cache: false,
                                    dataType: 'text',
                                    success: function(result){
                                    var data="";
                                    console.log(result);
                                    $('#bal').html('We will add 1000rs to your account soon');
                                    },
                                    error: function(error){console.log(error);}
                            });  

      });
```

php code:

```
<?php 

$bal=$_POST['balance'];

$bal=intval($bal);
echo $bal;

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre><br>';

echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Also, I have tried the solutions of:

1. [Undefined index: Error in ajax POST and/or php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136667/undefined-index-error-in-ajax-post-and-or-php-script)

   2. [jquery ajax => Undefined index php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467466/jquery-ajax-undefined-index-php)
   3. [Undefined index in PHP post with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023026/undefined-index-in-php-post-with-ajax)
   4. [Undefined index error in php using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642443/undefined-index-error-in-php-using-ajax)
   5. http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/jquery-json-php-undefined-index-950332.html

Snapshot of the ajax post request and PHP error

[image: Jquery ajax post on console and php error]

Comment: `var dataString = {balance};`  Should be `var dataString = {balance:balance};`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent, `{balance}` is correct syntax for `ES2015`

Comment: @vp_arth ES2015/ES6 is not yet natively supported in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part, you are not giving a valid syntax:

```
var dataString = {balance};
```

Change the above to:

```
var dataString = {balance: balance};
```

Comment: yes, i tried that. It didn't work. I also mentioned a link which mentioned the same solution. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @simrandhamija Can you please try doing the same with Chrome, and checking the Network tab, what's going on? A screenshot will be awesome.

Comment: I added the snap! unfortunately it is on firefox, hope you don't mind. Also i highlighted the relevant post request.

Comment: @simrandhamija Thanks. Can you also include the **form data** part in it? Sorry that was the main thing I was going behind...

Comment: @simrandhamija Do you really require this line? `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',`

Comment: @simrandhamija **Best Quick Fix:** Try using short hand. Replace your `$.ajax({ /* */});` with this: `$.post("admin.php", function (res) { $('#bal').html('We will add 1000rs to your account soon'); });` and tell me if that works.

Comment: The data i intend to send is not enclosed in a form. the button picks up the inner html of "balance" div, typecasts it to Integer, and posts it to admin. However, the first form is enclosed in <form></form> tag. When the first form's submit button is clicked, a second form replaces the first. Should i post that code too int the question? I have checked that portion, i doubt if it affects the issue.

Comment: @simrandhamija Check my last comment please. That should work. If not I am giving a 1000 ₹ right away! `:)`

Comment: Trying your best quick fix! thanks for that :). Will comment with the results

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I think you forgot to add the data in the `$.post()`...

Comment: @ImClarky The response is not at all considered in the post function...

Comment: @ImClarky I mean, it doesn't depend on the `res` or `data` or whatever.

Comment: @simrandhamija Do you have any element with `id="bal"` in your HTML? Can you kindly check, please?

Comment: yes, a span element. In my post above it is the first line of code. Any idea about the issue! stuck for 2 days now

Comment: @simrandhamija I could see only the element with `bal_val`, is that a typo? Did you mean to put `$("#bal_val")` instead?

Comment: sorry, i do have a "bal" div , added it to my post above. I use it to display messages

Comment: @simrandhamija Yup checked it. Any errors in Console? Come to chat.